# how to put database and read database from assets folder android which are created and exported in sqllite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new in Android development. I am making a database through SQLite Manager 0.8.1. The table Users contains two fields, username and password. I created the database file and put it in `assets` folder. Now I am trying to read the database from the assets folder. What's the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "YOURDBNAME";
    public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;

    }




    //Create a empty database on the system
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException
    {

          boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

          if(dbExist)
          {
                Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");
                // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
                // writeable database, but only if the version number has been
                // bumped
                //onUpgrade(myDataBase, DATABASE_VERSION_old, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }

          boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
          if(!dbExist1)
          {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try
                {
                      this.close();    
                      copyDataBase();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                      throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
          }

    }
    //Check database already exist or not
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
          boolean checkDB = false;
          try
          {
                String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                File dbfile = new File(myPath);
                checkDB = dbfile.exists();
          }
          catch(SQLiteException e)
          {
          }
          return checkDB;
    }
    //Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the system folder
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {

        InputStream mInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[2024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }
  //delete database
    public void db_delete()
    {
          File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
          if(file.exists())
          {
                file.delete();
                System.out.println("delete database file.");
          }
    }
  //Open database
    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
          String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
          myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void closeDataBase()throws SQLException
    {
          if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
          super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         if (newVersion > oldVersion)
         {
               Log.v("Database Upgrade", "Database version higher than old.");
               db_delete();
         }

    }

}
```

And to implement it

```
DataBaseHelper dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

For that:

```
Cursor cur;
    cur_Herbs = db.rawQuery("select * from TABLENAME where  name like '"
            + edit_text_name.gettext.tostring() + "'", null);

        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int name = cur.getColumnIndex("name");
                int pwd= cur.getColumnIndex("pwd");
str_name = cur.getString(name).toString();
                str_pwd= cur.getString(ped).toString();
if(str_name.equals(edittext_uname.gettext.tostring()and str_pwd.equals(edittext_pwd.gettext.tostring()))
{

//code for if loginn
}
} while (cur_Herbs.moveToNext());


}
```

Comment: thank you sir for reply now i want in my login activity fetch username and password from data base and store in variable and matched with user input how can i do thish and where i use DataBaseHelper dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: But is this the secure way of copying Files from Assets to Local Store. I mean Linux has a way with permissions, so if in a security review will this effect in any way?

Answer (score 7):

For those who have a problem to copy db from assets folder in **kotlin**:

```
private val DB_PATH = "/data/data/**YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME**/databases/"
private val DB_NAME = "**YOUR_DB_NAME**.db"

private fun copyDataBaseFromAssets(context: Context) {

        var myInput: InputStream? = null
        var myOutput: OutputStream? = null
        try {

            val folder = context.getDatabasePath("databases")

            if (!folder.exists())
                if (folder.mkdirs()) folder.delete()

            myInput = context.assets.open("databases/$DB_NAME")

            val outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME

            val f = File(outFileName)

            if (f.exists())
                return

            myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length: Int = myInput.read(buffer)

            while (length > 0) {
                myOutput!!.write(buffer, 0, length)
                length = myInput.read(buffer)
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput!!.flush()
            myOutput.close()
            myInput.close()


        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin code for doing that, you can find the explanation for each line above the line with a comment, but I'll give a small summary about how it works.

### How it gets created

When you create an object from `DBHelper` the class will check if the database already copied from the `assets` to the device if it's already copied, nothing will happen, but in case of it isn't exist on the device, the database will get copied to the device.

### How to use it

You can use it by creating a new instance from `DBHelper` then you can call any query method inside, *Please check the getQuestions method inside the DBHelper to know how to make a query*.
`val question = DBHelper(this).getQuestions(currentLevel)`

### My DB structure for reference

[image]

### The code:

```
// Replace this string with your .sql/.db file name
const val dbName = "db_name.db" 

// Database version number, you need to change it in case of any schema
// change.
const val dbVersionNumber = 1

class DBHelper(private val context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dbName, null, dbVersionNumber) {

  private var dataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null

  init {
    // Check if the database already copied to the device.
    val dbExist = checkDatabase()
    if (dbExist) {
      // if already copied then don't do anything.
      Log.e("-----", "Database exist")
    } else {
      // else copy the database to the device.
      Log.e("-----", "Database doesn't exist")
      createDatabase()
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    // if you want to do anything after the database created
    // like inserting default values you can do it here.
  }

  override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) { 
    // if you want to do anything after the database upgraded
    // like migrating values you can do it here.
  }

  // Copy the database
  private fun createDatabase() {
    copyDatabase()
  }

  // Check if the database already copied to the device.
  private fun checkDatabase(): Boolean {
    val dbFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path)
    return dbFile.exists()
  }

  // Copy the database
  private fun copyDatabase() {

    val inputStream = context.assets.open("dbs/$dbName")

    val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path)
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

    val bytesCopied = inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
    Log.e("bytesCopied", "$bytesCopied")
    inputStream.close()

    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
  }

  // Open the database with read and write access mode.
  private fun openDatabase() {
    dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(dbName).path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
  }

  // Close the database.
  override fun close() {
    dataBase?.close()
    super.close()
  }

  // An example of how you can make a query to get one item.
  // I have a database with one table called "questions"
  // I'm selecting one item at an index I'm passing to the
  // method.
  // My table has 6 columns: question, choice1, choice2, choice3
  // choice4, and correctAnswer.
  fun getQuestion(index: Int): Question {
    // before you make a query you need to open the database
    openDatabase()

    // Now you can make a query.
    val cursor = dataBase?.rawQuery("select * from questions limit 1 offset $index", null)

    // move to first will move the cursor to the first row.
    cursor?.moveToFirst()

    // now you can get the data from that row
    // all my columns is strings so i'm using "getString(index_of_column)"
    // but you can also use "getInt(index_of_column)" or any other
    // supported type.
    val question = cursor?.getString(0) ?: ""
    val choice1 = cursor?.getString(1) ?: ""
    val choice2 = cursor?.getString(2) ?: ""
    val choice3 = cursor?.getString(3) ?: ""
    val choice4 = cursor?.getString(4) ?: ""
    val correctAnswer = cursor?.getString(5) ?: ""

    // After using a cursor you need to close it, so the system can
    // release all its resources.
    cursor?.close()

    // After using the database you need to close it.
    close()

    return Question(question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, correctAnswer)
  }

  // An example of how you can make a query to get all the items.
  // I have a database with one table called "questions"
  // My table has 6 columns: question, choice1, choice2, choice3
  // choice4, and correctAnswer.
  fun getAllQuestions(): MutableList<Question> {
    // before you make a query you need to open the database
    openDatabase()

    // Now you can make a query.
    val cursor = dataBase?.rawQuery("select * from questions", null)

    // move to first will move the cursor to the first row.
    cursor?.moveToFirst()

    val array = mutableListOf<Question>()

    do {
      // now you can get the data from that row
      // all my columns is strings so i'm using "getString(index_of_column)"
      // but you can also use "getInt(index_of_column)" or any other
      // supported type.
      val question = cursor?.getString(0) ?: ""
      val choice1 = cursor?.getString(1) ?: ""
      val choice2 = cursor?.getString(2) ?: ""
      val choice3 = cursor?.getString(3) ?: ""
      val choice4 = cursor?.getString(4) ?: ""
      val correctAnswer = cursor?.getString(5) ?: ""

      // Add the question to the array.
      array.add(Question(question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, correctAnswer))

      // move to next will move the cursor to the next row if exist.
    } while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true)



    // After using a cursor you need to close it, so the system can
    // release all its resources.
    cursor?.close()

    // After using the database you need to close it.
    close()

    return array
  }


}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @NikolasRieble I have added comments.

Answer (score 0):

I also use that. I use a default database for my default data. Here is my sample code that works on my applicaiton.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.test/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "testDatabase";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

You can use this as reference. Hope this will help you.