# I am trying to import data from a .db file in a simple listView but my application is not displaying any text.How can i resolve this?

Tags: java, android, database, listview, import

I am a beginner in the android world and so I am learning to import data from an existing database created using DB browser. Below I am adding the link from which I am learning to import data from existing database file.
[How to import and use external database in android studio ?](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html)

NOTE: I have correctly placed the .db file in the assets folder.
I am sharing my `main.java` code below:

```
package com.javahelps.externaldatabasedemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
        databaseAccess.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My `activity_main.xml` file code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingStart="5dp"
android:paddingEnd="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My `DatabaseOpenHelper.java` class code is as follows:

```
package com.javahelps.externaldatabasedemo;

import android.content.Context;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quotes.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    } 
}
```

And lastly my `DatabaseAccess.java` class is :

```
package com.javahelps.externaldatabasedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;

    private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }
    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
    * Open the database connection.
    */
    public void open() {
        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
    * Close the database connection.
    */
    public void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            this.database.close();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Read all quotes from the database.
    *
    * @return a List of quotes
    */
    public List<String> getQuotes() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT quote FROM quotes", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem from the above code?

Comment: Can you post your log-cat, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial you have mentioned, the developer has put the `quotes.db.zip` file inside `assets/databases` directory. But you are mentioning that you have placed the .db file instead, please re-check.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the similar post. I hope it will help you. Find the link below: [how to put database and read database from assets folder android which are created and exported in sqllite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627776/4295522)

Also check the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```