# Android updating database in assets folder and copy it to phone

Tags: android, database, assets, copy-paste

I have an app receiving its data from a database in the assets folder. Now everyone has the app on their phones I want to update the database. I have the new database ready to go, but how to I get the updated database from the assets folder to their phones.

Comment: you can get the data from assets folder but u can`t update that file or data base.

Comment: asset db are read only type. when ever you will release new db version, onUpgrade() method will be invoke. write your logic inside this method.
refer this,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627776/1848157

Comment: you can do like this:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218941/9832121

then you can update it.

Comment: app is currently using so many people , so i need to add more rows or values into my new database , how can i add my new database without delete it, now my asset folder contain  new database, but i need to just copy new data to phone database without delete previous data

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You just have to write some code to add the new data to the phones database.